# gulp bower - angular is not installed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, bower

I was starting a new angular project generated with Yeoman (using gulp for the first time) but I have some problems (it's probably linked I think)

- When I do `gulp serve`, no error in the terminal but bower seems to do not inject dependencies. In the web inspector I have :

  ```
  <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  ```
- When I do `gulp test`, I get this error in terminal :

  ```
  PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
  at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gulp_test/app/scripts/app.js:11
  ```
- Same error when I do `gulp bower`

Anyone to help me and explain me why it's not working ?

EDIT : Just realized I still have angular error in web inspector doing `gulp serve`

Comment: On `grunt serve` does browser is getting opened automatically?

Comment: Thanks for responding. No it doesn't but I can open a browser at localhost:8080 and it seems to work (except that error)

Comment: if you are using gulp, why did you type `grunt serve`?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Typing error. I corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've work a bit on this yesterday and I finally found out.

For gulpfile.js, remove '/views' because the destination has to be your whole app not only the views :

```
gulp.task('bower', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.views.main)
  .pipe(wiredep({
directory: yeoman.app + '/bower_components',
    ignorePath: '..'
}))
```

`.pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.app) + '/views');`

```
});
```

In .bowerrc, I've change the path of bower_components to `app/bower_components`

I've changed all connect fonctions for (adding the middleware part) :

```
$.connect.server({
   root:['\.tmp', yeoman.app],
   livereload:true,
   port: 9000,
   middleware:function(connect, opt){
     return [['/bower_components', 
     connect["static"]('./bower_components')]]
   }
});
```

After a `bower install`, it worked like a charm.
I've found this solution here : https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1295